# Multi-tiered comment system Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, recursion, laravel-5

I'm having difficulty with blade recursive partial views. Everything works for the most part with the exception of recursion in the `comment.blade.php` file.

I know I need to use a foreach around the `@include('articles.comments.comment', $comment)` to call itself again, but I'm not sure how to call for it.

**article_comments** table:

```
id
message
user_id
parent_id
created_at
updated_at
```

**app\Article.php** Class:

```php
class Article extends Model {

    protected $table = 'articles';

    protected $fillable = [
        'category',
        'title',
        'permalink',
        'synopsis',
        'body',
        'source',
        'show_author',
        'published_at'
    ];

    protected $dates = ['published_at'];

    public function scopePublished($query)
    {
        $query->where('published_at', '<=', Carbon::now());
    }

    public function setPublishedAtAttribute($date)
    {
        $this->attributes['published_at'] = Carbon::parse($date);
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comments')->where('parent_id', 0);
    }

}
```

**app\Comments.php** Class:

```php
class Comments extends Model {

    protected $table = 'article_comments';

    protected $fillable = [
        'parent_id',
        'message',
    ];

    public function author() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); 
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comments', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function countChildren($node = null)
    {
        $query = $this->children();
        if (!empty($node)) {
            $query = $query->where('node', $node);
        }

        $count = 0;
        foreach ($query->get() as $child) {
            // Plus 1 to count the direct child
            $count += $child->countChildren() + 1; 
        }
        return $count;
    }

}
```

**app\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController.php**:

```
public function show($permalink)
{
    $article = Article::where('permalink', '=', $permalink)->with('comments','comments.author','comments.children')->first();
    if ($article != null) {
        $comments = $article->comments;
        return view('articles.show', compact('article','comments'));
    } else {
        return redirect('/')->with('error', 'This article does not exist.');
    }
}
```

**resources\views\articles\show.blade.php**

```
@if (count($comments) > 0)
    <ul>
    @foreach ($comments as $comment)
        @include('articles.comments.comment', ['comment'=>$comment])
    @endforeach
    </ul>
@else
    no comments
@endif
```

**resources\views\articles\comments\comment.blade.php**

```
<li>
    {{ $comment->message }}

    @if (count($comment->children) > 0)
        <ul>
        @foreach ($comment->children as $child)
            @include('articles.comments.comment', ['comment'=>$child])
        @endforeach
        </ul>
    @endif
</li>
```

***Current error:***

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: /var/www/dev.example.com/resources/views/articles/comments/comment.blade.php) (View:
```

Comment: Are you sure you are passing `$comments` to the view in your controller?

`return view('articles.show', compact('comments'));`

Comment: @OP I see you've extended your bounty.  Would you let us know how updating your classes to use standard eloquent relations (rather than home-grown queries) has affected the issue?

Comment: OK in your post it says you have a `comments` table but it shows the `Comment` class says `$table = "article_comments"`, what is the actual name of your comments table?

Comment: @OP I did some digging and it looks like there's a built-in method in blade called `@each` that handles some of this naturally.  You can give it a shot with my updated answer.  If that doesn't work, we need to `dd($comment->children)` and see what we're putting into the `foreach` that laravel doesn't seem to like.

Comment: @Jeff `@each` method returned the same error. Placing the `dd()` function in the `@foreach` returns a string `"1". (I really appreciate your continued efforts)

Comment: So `$comment->children` is returning `"1"`... that is weird!  Can you comment out the `countChildren()` function and see if it still does? I'm running out of ideas

Comment: @Jeff Strange... commenting it out did not affect anything. `dd($comment->children)` returns `"1"`, but `$comment->children` returns `<ul>1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</ul>`

Comment: @OP, I think now that it is pretty clear that you are passing corrupted data to your view.
you should dd($article) in `ArticlesController@show` to see exactly what data you are passing  to your view

Comment: @RajKamal It's showing this: http://i.imgur.com/eRw3Bz1.png

Comment: @OP, from that screenshot: Data is being **corrupted** for sure.
`children` should be a collection instead of "1".
but i can not say why. I can only suggest you to use xdebug or something and trace the problem.

Btw, you should modify `children()` function as  `$this->hasMany('App\Comments', 'parent_id')->where('parent_id','!=', 0);` this will make code clearer and *might* resolve  the problem.

Comment: @RajKamal I updated the children function to what you suggested but that didn't change children to a collection.

Comment: Where you return a `$this->hasMany()` you return actually an instance of `Relationship`, while appending `where` in `hasMany()->where()` will return an instance of `Builder`. Try returning only `hasMany()` without the ending `where`. Please take a look on my answer for that matter. If you still insist on adding `where`, do: `$relation = $this->hasMany()` then `$relation->getBaseQuery()->where()` then `return $relation`. You will preserve the relationship defined in the model.

Answer (score 10):

You're pretty close.  I think this should work:

**resources\views\articles\show.blade.php**

```
@if (count($comments) > 0)
    <ul>
        @each('articles.comments.comment', $comments, 'comment');
    </ul>
@else
    no comments
@endif
```

**resources\views\articles\comments\comment.blade.php**

```
<li>
    {{ $comment->message }}

    @if (count($comment->children) > 0)
        <ul>
            @each('articles.comments.comment', $comment->children, 'comment');
        </ul>
    @endif
</li>
```

**app\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController.php:**

```
$article = Article::where('permalink', '=', $permalink)->with('comments','comments.author','comments.children')->first();
$comments = $article->comments;
return view('articles.show', compact('article','comments'));
```

Comment: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: Is there something wrong with my `children()` function? I wrote out `{{ count($comment->children) }}` and they all return `1`. If I use `{{ App\Comments::find($comment->comment_id)->countChildren() }}` it returns the appropriate amount.

Comment: Does it work like `public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comments', 'id','parent_id');
    }`

Comment: @OP  ` @if (count($comment->children) > 0)` can you change it to  @if (is_array($comment->children)  || $comment->children instanceof  Traversable)  and check what you are getting ?

Comment: @OP please show us the results of `dd($comment->children)`

Comment: @Jeff it doesn't seem like anything is being returned

Comment: @OP There's got to be either a value or an error... how about `dd($comment)`? Or even just `dd($comments)` so we can confirm your query is returning a collection of Comments

Comment: Fixed `@include` statements to properly pass variables around. See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#control-structures

Comment: Maybe `@foreach ($comment->children() as $child)` ?

Comment: @Jeff it no longer returns an error with your updated post, however passing `{{ $comment->children }} in `comment.blade.php` returns an empty array `[]`, so all comments are still listed at the first level.

Comment: @Jeff @Mysteryos including `{{ count($comment->children) }}` returns 0, despite having a parent_id > 0

Comment: In your `ArticlesController.php`, you are loading the comments through a custom query builder. Instead, you should be eager-loading the comments with your article query as such `Article::where('permalink', '=', $permalink)->with('comments','comments.children','comments.user','comments.children.user')->first()`. Setup your relationships as appropriate.

Comment: In your comment class add `public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}`. Then when you fetch the comments its just `$article->comments` and the user data is just `$comment->author->username`. Mysteryos is right this is an issue with that query, just use relationships

Comment: @Jeff what is the `'comments'` parameter? It's causing `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::comments()` But that should already be defined?

Comment: @OP That suggests that you are calling `->comments()` on the Article query builder before you call `->first()` or `->get()` to retrieve the actual article.  See my edit for the controller code, assuming you've set up the relationships for Articles, Comments, and User.

Comment: @OP it might help if you update your question with the code you have now.

Comment: @Jeff updated to include all the changes I've implemented from your answer so far.

Comment: @Jeff I updated to the suggestions you provided in the edited post. Still receiving the same error.

Comment: @OP Can you post the stack trace of the error?  The actual exception is thrown in Builder.php but the stack should show us where we are calling `->comments()` on a query builder.

Comment: @OP yes, it looks like it cannot find the `comments` relation on the $article object, can you please post function `comments()` in your `Article.php`?

Comment: @Jeff added to my post. I guess I was missing it initially. This resolved the query builder error. Returning `$comments` in ArticlesController.php gives an array of the data I need! However, `show.blade.php` is having issues displaying them. It's unhappy with `@foreach ($comments as $comment)`. Updated post with new error.

Answer (score 6):

First, I see that you're laying all the comments in one page without any pagination, yet, you constrain your `comments()` method on the `Article` model to only comments having `parent_id=0` to get only the root comments. But, looking further at your code, in your controller, you're lazy loading `comments.author` and `comments.children` along. Note that the lazy loading will happen only for the first parent comments and after that, all the children will have to do a lot queries to get their relations by eagerly loading the relations.

If you stil want to lay all the comments in one page, I suggest you remove the `parent_id=0` constraint and load the comments all at once and apply a strategy to order them. Here's an example:

**app\Article.php**

```
class Article extends Model {

    // ...

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comments');
    }

}
```

**app\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController.php**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection; 

// ...

public function show($permalink)
{
    $article = Article::where('permalink', '=', $permalink)->with('comments','comments.author','comments.children')->first();

    if ($article != null) {

        $comments = $this->buildCommentTree($article->comments);

        return view('articles.show', compact('article','comments'));
    } else {
        return redirect('/')->with('error', 'This article does not exist.');
    }
}


protected function buildCommentTree(Collection $comments, $root = 0)
{
    $branch = new Collection();

    $comments->each(function(Comment $comment) use ($root) {
        if ($comment->parent_id == $root) {

            $children = $this->buildCommentTree($comments, $comment->getKey());

            $branch->push($comment);
        } else {
            // This is to guarantee that children is always a Collection and to prevent Eloquent 
            // from hitting on the database looking for the children
            $children = new Collection();
        }

        $comment->setRelation('children', $children);
    });

    return $branch;

}
```

Now that we have our comments all sorted without penalizing the database, we can start looping through the ads. I prefer to use two files instead of one for looping so I can reuse the code later.

**resources\views\articles\show.blade.php**

```
@if (!$comments->isEmpty())
    @include("articles.comments.container", ['comments'=>$comments])
@else
    no comments
@endif
```

**resources\views\articles\comments\container.blade.php**

```
@if (!$comments->isEmpty())
    <ul>
    @foreach ($comments as $comment)
        @include('articles.comments.show', ['comment'=>$comment])
    @endforeach
    </ul>
@else
```

**resources\views\articles\comments\show.blade.php**

```
<li>
    {{ $comment->message }}

    @if (!$comment->children->isEmpty())
        @include("articles.comments.container", ['comments'=>$comment->children])
    @endif
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

I might be missing something, but it looks to me like you have over complicated some of your code. For example, you could add a `user` relation to your comments model (You could also possibly remove the whole `count` method as well):

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Then whenever you need to access the user id or username of the commenter, you can just call:

```
$user_id = $comment->user->id;
$username = $comment->user->username;
```

Then you should be able to clean up a lot of your controller:

```
$article = Article::where('permalink', '=', $permalink)->first();
$comments = Comments::where('article_id', '=', $article->id)->get();
```

Your `show.blade.php` file should be just fine as is.
Your `comment.blade.php` file could be written this way:

```
<li>{{ $comment->message }}</li>
@if ($comment->children->count() > 0)
    <ul>
        @foreach($comment->children as $child)
            @include('articles.comments.comment', $child)
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

I believe your issue with the `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` error you are getting has to do with your original query for the comments. The error should be fixed by using the proper relational models.

As a side note, if you need to count your comment's children by a `node` column, you should be able to do something like this:

```
$comment->children()->where('node', $node)->get()->count();
```

Comment: Tried everything you said here. It doesn't seem to like this line `@if ($comment->children->count() > 0)` in the *comments.blade.php* view. Returns the error message `Call to a member function count() on a non-object`

Comment: Try updating your Comment's `children` relationship to this: `return $this->hasMany('App\Comments', 'parent_id')->with('children');`. That will call the children relationship recursively and may fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I simplified it a bit but this is what I would do:

Eloquent part:

```
class Article extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class)->where('parent_id', 0);
    }
}

class Comment extends Model
{
    public function article()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Article::class);
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'parent_id');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Controller/Route action part:

```
// Fetching article using your example:
$article = Article::where('permalink', '=', $permalink)->first();

// returning view somewhere below...
```

View part:
Article view:

```
@include('comments', ['comments' => $article->comments])
```

Comments view:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($comments as $comment)
        <li>
            <h2>{{ $comment->user->name }}</h2>
            <p>{{ $comment->message }}</p>
            @if(count($comments) > 0)
                @include('comments', ['comments' => $comment->children])
            @endif
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Please note that this is not very efficient if there are a lot of nested comments such as:

```
Comment
  -> Child Comment
    -> Child Child Comment
      -> Child Child Child Comment
```

A different way to structure this would be by by fetching all comments as once:

```
// Change the relation on the Article Eloquent model:
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

Assuming here the default value for parent_id is 0 then in your article view you could do something like this:

```
@include('comments', ['comments' => $article->comments, 'parent' => 0])
```

And in your comments view you could do something like this:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($comments as $comment)
        @if($parent === (int) $comment->parent_id)
            <li>
                <h2>{{ $comment->user->name }}</h2>
                <p>{{ $comment->message }}</p>
                @include('comments', ['comments' => $comments, 'parent' => (int) $comment->id])
            </li>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Update:
Looking at how you're still stuck with this I've uploaded an example: https://github.com/rojtjo/comments-example

Make sure check out the last commit, it shows the diff between the different methods I've used in the examples.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with the mysql database:

**Comment table structure**

```
id
commentable_id
commentable_type
parent_id
message
user_id
created_at
updated_at
```

**Article table structure**

```
id
content
user_id
created_at
updated_at
```

---

Your models will be setup as such: Comments model will be polymorphic, so that you may use your comments on other sections of your application. Note: I recommend moving your models to `app\models\` folder.

**app\Comments.php** Class:

```
namespace App

class Comments extends \Eloquent {

    /**
     * Name of the table to use for this model
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'comments';

    /**
     * The fields that are fillable
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = array(
        'commentable_type',
        'commentable_id',
        'message',
        'user_id',
        'parent_id'
    );

    /**
     * Commentable: Polymorphic relationship
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    /**
     * User: belongsTo relationship
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User','user_id');
    }

    /**
    * Parent Comment: belongsTo relationship
    *
    * @return \App\Comment | null
    */
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Comments','parent_id');
    }

    /**
    * Children Comment: hasMany relationship
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
    */        
    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comments','parent_id');
    }
}
```

**app\Articles.php** class:

```
namespace App

class Articles extends \Eloquent {
    /**
     * Name of the table to use for this model
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'articles';

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'content'
    ];

    /**
     * User: belongsTo relationship
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User','user_id');
    }

    /**
    * Comments: Polymorphic Relationship
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
    */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Comments','commentable');
    }

}
```

---

The article controller will be practically the same with the added code to eager load the comments and its children.

**app\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController.php:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Articles;

class ArticlesController extends Controller {
    /**
    * GET: View of an article
    *
    * @param string $permalink
    * @return \Illuminate\View\View
    */
    public function getView($permalink)
    {
        //Let's fetch the article
        $article = Articles::where('permalink','=',$permalink)
                    //Eager load relationships while applying conditions
                    ->with([
                    'comments' => function($query) {
                        //Utility method to orderBy 'created_at' DESC
                        return $query->latest();
                    },
                    'comments.children' => function($query) {
                        //Utility method to orderBy 'created_at' DESC
                        return $query->latest();
                    }
                    ])
                    ->first();

        //Generate the view
        return view('articles.show',['article'=>$article]);
    }
}
```

---

Finally, the views to display your data

**resources\views\articles\show.blade.php**

```
<h1>My article:</h1>
<div>
    <p>
        @if($article)
            {{$article->content}}
        @endif
    </p>
</div>

@if($article)
    <!-- Comments: START -->
    <div>
        @if (count($article->comments) > 0)
            <ul>
            @foreach ($article->comments as $comment)
                @include('articles.comments.comment', ['comment'=>$comment])
            @endforeach
            </ul>
        @else
            <span>no comments</span>
        @endif
    </div>
    <!-- Comments: END -->
@endif
```

**resources\views\articles\comments\comment.blade.php**

```
<li>
    {{ $comment->message }}
    <!-- Comment Children: START -->
    @if (count($comment->children) > 0)
        <ul>
            @foreach ($comment->children as $child)
                @include('articles.comments.comment', ['comment'=>$child])
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    @endif  
    <!-- Comment Children: END -->
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I sort of refactored your Comments.php. You can try this:

**app\Comments.php**

```
class Comments extends Model {

protected $table = 'article_comments';

protected $fillable = [
    'parent_id',
    'message',
];

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comments', 'parent_id');
}

public function countChildren($node = null)
{
    $query = $this->children();
    return (!empty($node)) ? $query->where('node', $node)->count() : $query->count();
}
}
```

**resources\views\articles\comments\comment.blade.php**

```
<li>{{ $comment->message }}</li>  
@if (App\Comments::find($comment->comment_id)->countChildren() > 0)
<ul>
    <li>{{ $comment->message}}</li>
    @include('articles.comments.comment', ['comment' => $comment])
</ul>
@endif
```

**resources\views\articles\show.blade.php**

```
@if (count($comments) > 0)
<ul>
    @foreach ($comments as $comment)
      @include('articles.comments.comment', ['comment' => $comment])
    @endforeach
</ul>
@else
 no comments
@endif
```